# Anchor tags indent when clicked on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, hyperlink

The site I've been working on can be found here: [Scroll Based Site](http://morrisonhosting.com/php/portfolio/scroll/)
and it runs as a simple page with anchors on and it scrolls using jQuery to the correct place on the page when a menu item is clicked. This worked on both mobile and desktop. In my attempts to make a mobile friendly version I made the following CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#header {
    width: 100%;
}

#home {
    width: 100%;
}

#features {
    width: 100%;
}

#colors {
    width: 100%;
}

#contact {
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
}

#nav li a {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px){
    #nav li a:hover {
        color: #a2a2a2;
    }

    #footer a:hover {
        color: #a2a2a2;
    }

    #logo {
        display: none;
    }

    * {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }

    #header {
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #nav {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }

    #nav li a {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }


    #footer {
        padding: 13px 0;
    }

    #footer a {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    #colors img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This seemed to be working, but for whatever reason it started to indent when you click on the menu links which you can test: [Here at Responsivator](http://dfcb.github.io/Responsivator/?site=morrisonhosting.com/php/portfolio/scroll)

This indenting doesn't actually happen on a phone, but on a phone via touch the associated event never happens in the javascript so it's clearly still a problem.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can remedy this?

Comment: Try adding the same css instructions in both `#nav li a` and `#nav li a:hover` selectors, just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much. That made me feel like an idiot. I guess all I needed was an extra set of eyes.

Comment: I'm glad that helped =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange, but with developer tools I found this in main.css on line 50:

```
#nav li a, #nav li a:active, #nav li a:visited {
color: #a2a2a2;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 50px;
transition: color .5s ease;
-moz-transition: color .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: color .5s ease;
-o-transition: color .5s ease;
}
```

remove the #nav li a:active and it should work as aspected.

Comment: And that was an error on my part. Both work but Frederik's comment wasn't the route of the problem that active was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need `#nav li a` and `#nav li a:hover` to have the same css instructions.

Comment: The other answer was truely the root of the problem so I accepted it, though this is just as valid if I had kept the a:active in the main.css file (the one that is served first).